# How to Set WordPress Taxonomy Pages to NOINDEX

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

What code can I add to my WordPress Child Theme that will insert `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` into the `<head>` of taxonomy pages only? Specifically "tags" pages.

I've done this with a plugin like Yoast but I need to get this done without a plugin.

Comment: In your `header.php` in your child theme, add `if (is_tag()) : echo '<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />'; endif;` anywhere before the closing `</head>`

Comment: I've tried this, and multiple variations, it doesn't work.

Comment: Show us your attempts. We don't know what custom code you've tried. Is the `meta` tag not showing up when you view source?